# Use file contents in terminal command

Tags: command-line

Is there a way to pipe the contents of a file into a terminal command? For example, suppose I have a program `add` which just adds its two arguments. I'd like to know how to do this:

```
$echo 2 2 > filename
$add SOME_SYNTAX(filename)
4
```

In other words, `add` gets its arguments out of a file I specify, instead of me having to type them manually. What should replace `SOME_SYNTAX()` to make this work?

Comment: you can do something like `add "$(<filename)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file_content="`cat filename`"
```

will store the contents of filename into file_content.

You can append something to a file using `>>` instead of `>`.

```
echo 2 2 >> filename   
echo 2 2 >> filename    
echo 2 2 >> filename
```

would add it 3 more times to your `echo 2 2 > filename`